# jquery load interval div flash

Tags: php, jquery, sql, css, html

So, I have a div that im using the following code on, but it will flash when it reloads. I understand 1000 is ridiculous - it's simply set at that while im testing. Is there anyway to avoid the "flash" as if that div were a page reload?

Thanks, so much!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#timelinerContainers").load("jquery_timeline.php");
       var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
          $("#timelinerContainers").load('jquery_timeline.php');
       }, 1000);
       $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
</script>
```

If I click ANYWHERE on the page it then will stop flashing... Rather odd.

Thanks so much for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
$("#timelinerContainers").fadeOut().load('jquery_timeline.php').fadeIn();
```

or

```
$("#timelinerContainers").fadeOut().load('jquery_timeline.php',function(){
    $(this).fadeIn()
});
```

Comment: That just changes it to fading in/out. The problem is it's on the interval reloading the div entirely when it does the DB query. Which is good, but it's causing a "disappear" ... "reappear". Which is what I am trying to avoid, it's like a hard refresh. I want to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $.ajax({
            url: "jquery_timeline.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#timelinerContainers").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The change is that I've used the `jQuery.ajax()` function for loading the contents. What I've done here is to first load the contents and then update the div, instead of clearing the contents, before making the ajax request.